# Curve flattens when converted to 2D

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: to]

I have never had this problem before, and it only applies to this curve in specific.

Do you know what's going on?

[image]

Comment: can you plz share the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: okay, I added the blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Edit mode select all and **Rotate in X axis.**

Out of Edit mode. Click 2D

In the **Fill** select **Both**

[image]